# spring boot security properties not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

i am not able to access /beans endpoint after adding the security properties in application.properties.
my all files are like this.

SpringActuator.java

```
package com.spring.actuator;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringActuatorApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringActuatorApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
management.security.enabled=true
security.user.name=act
security.user.password=act
management.security.roles=ACTUATOR
management.context-path=/manage
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.spring.actuator</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringActuator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SpringActuator</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

In all tutorials, configurations are just like this and everybody got running their actuator endpoint. but i am not able do that. please point out any mistake i made.

thanks

Comment: Can you try adding **@EnableWebSecurity** anotation in your SpringActuator class

Comment: @mrt it worked. thank you so much. actually i did that in past but my spring security-core jar got corrupt and i am not able to use EnableWebSecurity annotation. and also i follow a tutorial which tells that you don't have to add spring-security dependency for that. so removed it. but now i think spring-security dependency is must. thanks again.